# Java из javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Есть большой javascript код, который работает на сайте, она коннектится и создает чат, как можно переделать этот javascript в java

к примеру вот этот не понятный для меня код

```
    this.login = function(options) {

        if (typeof (options.success) == "function" && typeof (options.error) == "function" && options.params != null) {
            var successCallback = options.success;
            var errorCallback = options.error;
        } else {
            AV.console.error(LP + 'Invalid number of arguments (min req = 3), Please read API Documentation.');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: _sURL + '/csportal/v1/login',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(options.params),
            success: function(response) {
                AV.console.debug(LP + "login::Success: " + JSON.stringify(response));
                if (response && response.success == true) {
                    _userLoggedIn = 'true';
                    _userReturned = 'false';
                    _userInfo = response.data;
                    successCallback({"message": response.message,"data": response.data});
                } else {
                    _userLoggedIn = 'false';
                    errorCallback({message: response.message});
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                AV.console.warn(LP + "login:: error: " + e.message);
                errorCallback({message: e.responseText});
            }
        });
    };
```

можно ли его как то переделать

Comment: Начать с того, что изучить оба языка.

Comment: Вы хотите переписать клиентский JS-код в виде Java-апплета или как? Java нельзя просто взять и выполнить в браузере.

Comment: Можете посмотреть сюда: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html правда не уверен, что это хорошая идея.

Comment: Спасибо, нет я хочу делать такие же запросы со своего сервера, но вот к примеру в javascript делается запрос к серверу с json, как мне сделать такой же запрос на java.

Comment: Пример отправки POST запроса можете посмотреть в [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1359700).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Изучите что делает код на `javascript`
2. Сделайте тоже самое на `Java`

Код делает, примерно, следующее:

1. Создаёт `POST` запрос на адрес типа `ДОМЕННОЕ_ИМЯ+/csportal/v1/login`
2. Устанавливает общий тип передаваемых данных в `application/json`
3. Устанавливает конкретный тип данных в `json`
4. Записывает данные в запрос из значения переменной `options.params`, кои преобразует в `JSON` формат методом `JSON.stringify()
5. Далее слушается ответ/результат запроса и в случае удачи устанавливаются переменные `_userLoggedIn` в `true` и `_userInfo` инициализируется данными ответа.
6. Также вызывает options.success или options.error в зависимости от успешности

Ещё подробнее не расскажу, ибо в яваСкриптом ни разу в жизни дел не имел.
Задавайте отдельный конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Хочу сделать запрос на сервер как из javascript,

Comment: @JTan, в сети множество информации по запросам в сеть на яве с авторизацией на сервере и передачей/получением данных. Если что-то будет не понятно - задайте конкретный отдельный вопрос по непонятному. За вас никто код перевести на другой язык не возьмётся.

Comment: да мне хотя бы пример вот этого кода, что здесь творится, уже долгое время бьюсь, остальное бы я сам бы разбирал, или хотя бы объяснить что здесь происходит.

Comment: @JTan, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, еще вызывает options.success или options.error в зависимости от успешности.

Comment: @dzhioev, да, спс, добавил в ответ) Сразу не обратил внимания - уж очень непонятен этот-ваш-яваскрипт)

Comment: Подскажите еще как мне правильно будет сделать запрос на сервер, что мне надо использовать, могу ли я как то сокетом на этот 80 порт или как то по другому надо

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы про чистую яву (не андроид)  - как в ней не знаю. По идее должна подойти любая либа, позволяющая делать `POST` запросы. Что такое сокет - не знаю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб большое вам спасибо, выручили